# Injecting StyleSheet Object into Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to get a page's style sheet object using the stylesheet api and then inject that into an iframe that already had that page's HTML? So that you don't have to get all the CSS files. Also assuming this is happening on the same domain.

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip: if both pages use the same CSS files, your browser will most likely cache them and load them only once. http://imgur.com/aIsLnEG

Comment: I'm going with @blex here, but it's better to tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish rather than how to accomplish what you think you need to do

Comment: @Adam essentially I want my iframe to update as the css and HTML of the iframe is updated. So if I have direct access to the stylesheet object then I don't need to worry about injecting javascript into the iframe and can just update the css/ HTML instead using the dom objects.

Comment: is it possible to simply serve the same CSS assets that are in the parent also in the head of the document loaded in the iframe? AS @blex pointed out, they're probably going to be cached by the user anyway (provided you have set the appropriate cache headers), and if you set the really good cache headers it won't even result in a server hit 304 response - it'll be read directly from disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate `document.styleSheets`, create a `<link>` element with `href` set to `href` of the current `CSSStyleSheet`, append the `<link>` element to `body` of `<iframe>` `.contentDocument`

```
const sheets = document.styleSheets;
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
console.log(iframe.contentDocument.head)
for (let {href} of sheets) {
  const link = document.createElement("link");
  link.href = href;
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(link)
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xl544x0FMn0WdnjioOl7?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! Any idea how to replicate this for chrome and safari. Since it's not working there

Comment: @MustafaKhan The code was tried at Chromium. Can you describe "not working" and create a plnkr to demonstrate?

Comment: Ohh I figured it out. Thank you again!

Comment: @MustafaKhan But How did you figured it out?